# Converting a California Coordinate System Zone 6 value

Tags: coordinate-system, google-earth

On this page: [State Plane Coordinate System - Convert, View on Google Earth](http://www.earthpoint.us/StatePlane.aspx) I have entered:

```
0406 California Zone 6
X (meters) 1895486.55
Y (meters) 329169.63
```

Then "Calc" produces:

```
Degrees Minutes Seconds     30°37'18.7129", -117°20'20.1205"
```

Using Google Earth it lands off the west coat of Baja California rather than in San Diego County, California  near Julian as expected given the source document: [image: Grant Deed for a segment of CA Hwy 79, 1954] [image: Coordinate System Zone 6]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I bet those values are US survey feet, and based on the document, also on NAD 1927, not NAD 1983.

The app you're using is using the NAD 1983 definitions of the State Plane zones. The parameters are different, so you're not going to be able to convert NAD 1927 coordinates using it.

If I convert the given values (cropping to integers) using the NAD 1927 definition, I get

```
longitude = -116.591154
latitude = 33.0709033
```

Comment: Good catch so it should be https://www.google.com/maps/place/2949+California+79,+Julian,+CA+92036,+USA/@33.0695873,-116.5856364,14z/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x80dbd06eaeb74599:0xe130e259b89f39f6

Comment: Is there a web link for using NAD 1927?

Comment: NGA has one [here](http://www.ngs.noaa.gov/cgi-bin/spc_getgp.prl) but it won't automatically send the results to Google Maps or Earth.

Comment: Ack. I meant *NGS* (National Geodetic Survey) not NGA.